# Mobx forcing computed values to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, mobx

I'm using Mobx to handle some state in my React app.

My app uses JWT for auth. via a token and a refresh token.

I've got a store set up and working as follows:

```
class generalStore {
    isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('token') !== null ? true : false;
    name = localStorage.getItem('token') !== null ? jwtdecode(localStorage.getItem('token')).name : null;
    role = localStorage.getItem('token') !== null ? jwtdecode(localStorage.getItem('token')).role : null;

    login(name, role) {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }

    logout() {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
        this.name = null;
        this.role = null;
    }
}

decorate(generalStore, {
    isLoggedIn: observable,
    name: observable,
    role: observable,
    login: action,
    logout: action
})

const store = new generalStore()
```

This works as expected when login/logout is called elsewhere in the app.

However, if the JWTs are malformed (manually via the dev. console) the `jwtdecode` function throws and error and the whole app crashes - not ideal. I am probably being paranoid, malformed JWTs should not happen all that often in the wild, but I like being robust.

I then thought I could use computed values to mitigate with this:

```
class generalStore {
    constructor() {
        try {
            this.decoded = jwtdecode(localStorage.getItem('token'))
        } catch(err) {
            this.decoded = null
        }
    }

    get isLoggedIn() {
        if (this.decoded) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }


    get name() {
        if (this.decoded) {
            return this.decoded.name
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    get role() {
        if (this.decoded) {
            return this.decoded.role
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

decorate(generalStore, {
    isLoggedIn: computed,
    name: computed,
    role: computed,
})
```

But the computed values do not update automatically when local storage updates with new tokens on login, the app must be refreshed (and therefore the store too) before the computed values reflect the now present tokens.

Is there a way to force an update of computed values? Or can I handle `jwtdecode` throwing an error when defining observables in my store (first code block)?

Or should not concern myself with malformed JWTs? It seems like I probably should if I'm being responsible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is  not working because `this.decoded` is not observable, and therefore mobx can't track updates to it in order to force the computed property to update.

In all of the [mobx examples](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html) they are using computed properties that are based on other observable values.

So your options are to make `decoded` observable, or to use a method instead of a computed property.

```
class generalStore {

    decoded = null;

    constructor() {
        try {
            this.decoded = jwtdecode(localStorage.getItem('token'))
        } catch(err) {
            this.decoded = null
        }
    }

    // ...
}

decorate(generalStore, {
    decoded: observable,
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I can't work out how to define `decoded` as an observable within the constructor function, or outside of the constructor function with a try/catch block to mitigate malformed JWTs.

Comment: @BML91 check out the examples [here](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/modifiers.html) There is a class ```Person``` with some class properties and then below they are marked as observable

Comment: That's how I'm defining my classes - as I'm not using decorators. None of those examples illustrate how to do try/catch observable outside of a constructor or how to define an observable using a try/catch block?